# In search of a lightweight Java cache with usage tracking for closable items

Tags: java, caching

I am looking for a Java-library that acts as a `cache` with usage-tracking for caching keyed objects that are expensive to create, need to be closed on removal, and may be shared across threads.

I identified the following requirements:

**Cache-Properties:**

- size-based eviction (configurable maximum size)
- items that are Least-Recently-Used should be considered for eviction first
- clean-up on eviction (close resources of the item being removed)
- map-like access (key-value)
- items should be kept as long as possible as they are expensive to create (so weak-references like in `guava` or `caffeine` do not seem to be an option)

**Usage-Tracking-Properties:**

- items can be marked as "in use"
- items that are "in use" are not evicted and retrieval of a new item may block when the cache is full and currently nothing can be removed
- the "Usage-Tracking-Properties" may also be replaced by a possibility to avoid eviction based on some runtime property of the item that the cache wants to remove

**General:**

- a lightweight library would be preferable

**What I found so far:**

- `ehcache` has the possibility to configure an `EvictionAdvisor` which sounded promising, but unfortunately it "may only be invoked when a mapping is written to the cache" an, therefore "expected to be constant for a key-value pair". Maybe it is an option to overwrite the mapping every time the usage-status changes - but that does not sound optimal...

Comment: Maybe add a bit what your application is actually doing to avoid the XY Problem. Questions: How long would an item be "in use"? How many items are cached and how many would be in use at a time?

Comment: EHCache has a "Pinning" feature, I think that is what you are looking for. In future, I'd like to put something similar into [cache2k](https://cache2k.org).

Comment: @cruftex thanks alot for your input! the resources are weekly-partitioned search indices and the actual usage time is in the range of milliseconds (when documents are written, the index is queried or deleted) and there may be indices that are used with high frequency (especially for writing when it's the index of the current week). 

Currently I am using a solution involving a guava-cache for storing everything and eviction and a ConcurrentHashMap for the resources currently in use - it works, but is far from optimal as it needs a lot of synchronization.

I will have a look at the pinning.

Comment: I doubt that EHCache will be faster than what you currently have.